# Interpolation of satellite image with overlapping areas

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation

I am having a problem with interpolation of the satellite images. I understand how the satellite taking image of the earth:

[image]

and I am trying to perform an interpolation by using following code:

```
import scipy as sc
import scipy.interpolate as spi
import numpy as np

def interpolate_data(img, lat, lon):

p_x, p_y = sc.mgrid[-1:1:lat.shape[0]*1j, -1:1:lon.shape[1]*1j] 
n_x, n_y = sc.mgrid[-1:1:img.shape[0]*1j, -1:1:img.shape[1]*1j] 
n_lat = spi.griddata((p_x.ravel(), p_y.ravel()), lat.ravel(), (n_x, n_y), method='linear') 
n_lon = spi.griddata((p_x.ravel(), p_y.ravel()), lon.ravel(), (n_x, n_y), method='linear')
print "n_lat:",n_lat.shape
print "n_lon:",n_lon.shape
print "img:",img.shape
return n_lat, n_lon
```

But if I interpolate in this way, I will have incorrect data.

In my case, the satellite is gonna take 9 shots of the earth. Between curve A and curve B is the area that taken by the satellite in the first shot. Between curve C and curve D is the area taken by the satellite in the second shot. E and F are the area that overlapping.

If I use the code above to interpolate, I will count the overlapping area twice and give me wrong data. So I want to ask if there is a way to count those overlapping area just once. Thanks.

[image]

If I use the code above to interpolate, I will count the overlapping area twice and give me wrong data. So I want to ask if there is a way to count those overlapping area just once. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images have geographical extent data attached (e.g. GeoTIFF files) you could consider using the [GDAL library](http://www.gdal.org/), this library is written in C/C++ but also has a [python package](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython).

It can work with dozens of different formats and has several different image processing methods for image warping and transforming.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just concatenate data from all of 9 shots, and interpolate all at once?  I don't see any reason to treat those nine dataset separately.  And if you do have one, I think you better create 9 different images.